# How to use same button with different functionality in different Fragments using same layout file in TabActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have a question from last few days. I basically have three fragments in a TabActivity, Fragment A, Fragment B and Fragment C. All three Fragments contain a list of CardView of approximately 14 CardViews in single Fragment. This three Fragment share same layouts with same cardview with same id. There is a button in each CardView and i want to start different activity's when clicked on that button. But I cant do it because id for button is same and I want to start activity's when that button is clicked from different Fragments. I am using RecyclerView for this. It means I have 14 buttons in a Fragment and there are three Fragments.

Comment: Okay, but where is the button click listener ?

Comment: If your project is small, you can send me your project zip and I will add the required code in your project

Comment: Where i can send you my project?

Comment: send me a dropbox link here after uploading to dropbox

Comment: These three files are my whole project. There is nothing more to share.

Comment: Okay. I will be back in 5 minutes. Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: I have updated my answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gleox5zyhiki16h/AAA4Ay1SmX29Alo1aGDiT8wVa?dl=0

Comment: I have added a link of my all java classes and layout files in it.

Comment: Did you check my updated answer ? I am afraid, if you can't send me the whole project zip, I cant help you. I can't create a project from your files.

Comment: No, its not project zip. I need the project which I can directly open and do the changes and send you back, not these separate files.

Comment: Wait I will send you zip now. My net is slow. size is 52mb.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xk7mevq178cel97/Notes.zip?dl=0

Comment: I have added zip. Its 25 MB.

Comment: Okay, I will check it now

Comment: What do you want to do on clicks of each fragments ?

Comment: There are three Framents. Each fragment have 6, 6 and 3 Cardview respectively with exactly same layout. I have 15 other activities which i want to open when user click on that button on each cardview.

Comment: Here is the updated project :https://www.dropbox.com/s/qw4i6f14d763abv/Notes.zip?dl=0

Please mark my answer accepted if it helps you. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @intellignt_idiot Thanks a lot. Your every code was running and working. You have helped me a lot and solved my problem in just one day. But I also have made some changes in my file. I will tell you in my updated question above.

Comment: I am glad to hear that it worked.
If you have any other questions, please post a separate question.
Good luck for the rest of your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button is in recyclerView, you can set a click listener of that button in XML, which will be called in Your Activity. Now your recyclerView adapter , set a tag which will be the position of the cell to you your button.

```
holder.imageButton.setTag(position);
```

Now, in your main activity, create an integer variable named

```
int currentSelectedTab = 0;
```

and then do this on your TabChange listener.;

```
 mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            selectedTab = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Now you will always have the current selected tabPosition.

And in clicklistener in your Activity do this ::

```
  public void myOnClick(View v) {

if(current selectedTab == 1)
{

if(v.getId === R.id.btn1)
{

// it means btn of Fragment 1 is clicked
// same goes for other button clicks
// and for the index of button
// v.getTag() it will you which cell's button was clicked

 }
```

In your cardView xml :

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/chapter_description"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:onClick="myOnClick"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/description"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"/>
```

Comment: hey can you now help me out. I have posted my code now. Please. It will be a great help.

Comment: The button that you are talking about is the one whose id is chapter_description ?

Comment: Yeah, It is a button i am using three different fragments. I want them to do different things. But the layout I am using for three fragments is same.

Answer (score 1):

Implement on click listener in your activity.
On each button click programatically do whatever changes you want to do in the layout..

Example below

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
            // Do something 
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            // Do something
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            // Do something
    }
}
```